# notifyDatasetChanged does not work on Gridview, unless devices has been rotated

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-gridview

This is really an odd problem. The basic gist of it is what the title says. I have an adapter, which I am updating and calling `notifyDatasetChanged()` The problem however, is it does not work, unless the device has been rotated at least once. I can't for the life of me figure out why, what is being done differently after a rotation occurs?

The code in question is here:

The ASyncTask that handles it..

```
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Records> result) {

        if (ca == null)
        {
            ca = new CoverAdapter<Records>(c, R.layout.grid_cover_with_text_item, result);
        }

        if (gv.getAdapter() == null)
        {
            gv.setAdapter(ca);
        }
        else
        {
            new AdapterHelper().update((CoverAdapter) ca, result);
            ca.notifyDataSetChanged;
        }

    }
```

With "ca" being my `adapter`, "gv" being my `GridView` and `AdapterHelper().update` being a method I found here to clear the adapter and add all the results of the `arraylist` to it, so it should be being updated properly.

Remember, this code works after the device has been rotated. Very confused right now, any insight would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need a new class to clear and update the contents of an `ArrayList` that is assigned to an `Adapter`?  As for the `unless the device has been rotated at least once`, use the debugger and step through the code to check what is expected actually happens.

Comment: @techiServices The adapter's underlying data is being changed, the class is simply a helper for a foreach loop to insert the updated data into the adapter.

After stepping through the code multiple times, nothing is different except for something I found very interesting. On first launch, the fragment's index is 0, but after a rotation (and any rotations thereafter) it's index is 1. The code works when the index is 1, but not 0. If it helps, I'm using the support library's `FragmentPagerAdapter`

Comment: Why does that require a new class?  Why not just use a function..?

Comment: I suppose. I can switch that to use the adapter's `.addAll()` method, which does the same thing. Unfortunately, the problem still persists. Going to continue combing through my adapters to see what's going on.

Comment: Ah, the problem was outside the scope of where I thought it was. Turns out I was running the ASyncTask (and it was completing) before the fragment was instantiated. Thanks for the help regardless!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the debugger and step through the code to check what is expected actually happens.

Glad you found the problem... Now you can ditch the `AdapterHelper`class which is a waste.